# Handling 30,000 pageviews per day using a t2.micro instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have a t2.micro instance and I predict 30,000 pageviews per day in the coming week. Each page view has 2-3 mysql queries and each of it takes `0.0009 sec` as it shows from the console.  Static content is from cloudfront and the overall transfer from ec2 per page is around 10KB. Will the instance be able to bear the load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It significantly depends on what you are doing. I suggest to play with load testing tools. There are plenty of those on the internet. Loadimpact is one of examples (there are many others): https://loadimpact.com/

Comment: Thanks @Artem for your reply. I got my website tested on loadimpact and I got this output - http://i.imgur.com/DeU3XU1.jpg .Am I wrong to interpret that my site can handle 25 concurrent users? Or what does this result mean? I cannot quite easily figure out what this test signifies. It will be a great help if you could tell me what it means. Thanks

Comment: I believe that means that your website would withstand 25 concurrent users. With the speed you serving your pages (up to a second) you should be able to server up to 86400*25 = 2M users a day if they are evenly distributed. If all your users will come during an hour you still should be alright: 3600*25 = 90K. You might want to pay some service if you want to test higher number of concurrent users, but seems like you are alright. Another issues though is that if your site will go down there are no clustered server to mirror it.

Comment: Thanks Artem your reply solved my problem. For downtime I am considering launching another t2.micro instance and using ELB. Am I right there?

Comment: The way it usually works is that you'd have 2 instances and ELB in front of of them to distribute load evenly. If ELB detects that one of the instanced died it immediately removes it from the balanced list of instances and keep working with only alive one.